# How do I get the ratio of stirling numbers?

Tags: stirling-numbers

How do I get the ratio: $\sum_{i=k}^n (-1)^{i+k}\left\{\begin{array}{l}
n \\
i
\end{array}\right\}\left[\begin{array}{c}
i \\
k
\end{array}\right]=\delta_{n,k}$ ?
We know the ratios $x^{\underline{n}}=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k}\left[\begin{array}{c}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right]x^k$
$x^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \left\{\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right\}x^{\underline{k}}$
We substitute the first into the second and get $x^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \left\{\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right\}x^{\underline{k}}=\sum_{k=0}^n \left\{\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right\}\sum_{m=0}^k (-1)^{m+k}\left[\begin{array}{c}
k \\
m
\end{array}\right]x^m$
How do I change the summation to equate the coefficients for $x^i$?

Comment: Hint: change of basis of the vector space of polynomials of degree at most $n$, between the two bases $(x^k)_k$ and $(x^{\underline{k}})_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that the inner sum can be extended to $n$ because the Stirling number will just be zero and then notice that you can exchange the sums because they are finite. To finish, notice that $k<m$ vanishes and so
$$\sum _{k=0}^n{n\brace k}\sum _{m=0}^n(-1)^{m+k}{k\brack m}x^m=\sum _{m=0}^nx^m\sum _{k=0}^n(-1)^{k+m}{n\brace k}{k\brack m}=\sum _{m=0}^nx^m\sum _{k=m}^n(-1)^{k+m}{n\brace k}{k\brack m}.$$